# Facebook install ads integration

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-ads-api

Can we create test ads for specific testers, without paying for the adds to test them. Like we can do for adMobs.

I wanna create an install ad for my app on facebook and test it on my device before purchasing it from facebook.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to show (mobile) ad to someone without paying for it is "View on mobile" link, which can be found in FB's Adverts Manager after clicking the eye icon at ad detail.

The ad will show up in FB app, but only for the person who clicked the link, so you'l need your testers to access Adverts Manager.

The preview should be fully functional and include all necessary tracking for 3rd parties, with exception of impressions, spend and other FB stats which aren't tracked for ad previews. If you need more details on the tracking, your integration partner should be able to help you.